# Send data from Android Library to Main Project Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to send string from Android Library to a method in my Main Project Activity. How best can I do this

This is what I have tried

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17912254

But It gives me this error

java.lang.ClassCastException: zw.com.ianmanda.paynowandroid.PostPayment cannot be cast to zw.com.ianmanda.paynowandroid.OnTaskFinishedListener

Comment: Elaborate more on your question. Have you tried anything so far? What errors do you get with the current code and post it here. Please follow these tips http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am currently wanting to pass this data from an AsyncTask in my library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Library Activity:
   try {
                Intent itemintent = null;

                try {
                    itemintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Class.forName("your packagename with class name"));//Ex com.example.test.Activity
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putStringArray("iarray", Array1);
                 b.putString("key", "YourString");
                b.putInt("mflag", 0);
                itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);
                startActivityForResult(itemintent, 2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

In your mainActivity:

```
     Bundle b =  startingIntent.getBundleExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT");
if (b != null) {

           String[] strA = b.getStringArray("iarray");
           String value=b.getString("key","")
        }
```

Comment: if the answer is satified you please upvote to this answer @Harian Manda

Comment: is this the way to let my library using developers to get data?