# How to send an Intent From an activity in Library Module to the Main Applications's activity

Tags: android, android-intent, module, android-library

I am trying to send an intent from an activity in library module to the activity in main app .But unable to send as the library module cannot have dependency on the main application resulting in circular dependencies.
Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send data from Android Library to Main Project Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221449/send-data-from-android-library-to-main-project-activity)

Comment: thanks mate .....cheers

Comment: if that answer is satisfied you please upvote that answer @Karan Veer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to reference to `MainActivity` class name in library. Just add an `intent-filter` to `MainActivity` in your main app manifest:

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.example.main.mainactivity" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And in your library just call this to open `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.main.mainactivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

**Note:** Defining `intent-filter` for activity implicitly sets `android:exported` to `true`. It means that other apps can use a same intent to launch your activity. If it is an issue, use [permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#prmsn) to limit your activity.